# JavaFX8 FXML Controller injection

Tags: controller, javafx-8, fxml

In my GUI app I have two views: **playlistView.fxml** and **videoView.fxml**. Each have their own controllers. I want **playListView** to be part of the **videoView** layout, so I use:

```
<fx:include fx:id="idPlayListAnchorPane" source="playListView.fxml" />
```

to include the file. Works fine, the playlist shows up as part of the videoView layout.

Then I inject the **idPlayListAnchorPane** FXML variable into the **VideoViewController** like this:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane idPlayListAnchorPane;
```

Works too. For example I can disable the **idPlayListAnchorPane** in the **playListView** from the **VideoViewController** with:

```
idPlayListAnchorPane.setDisable(true);
```

To get the playListViewController I use:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/designer/views/video/playListView.fxml"));
    PlayListViewController playListViewController = new PlayListViewController();
    loader.setController(playListViewController);
    try {
        AnchorPane playListView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    };
```

and then I can call for example:

```
playListViewController.init();
```

from the **videoViewController**.

But the init() method creates some test values in the **playListView** ListView (tested as a separate app and that works). However these test values now don't show up in the ListView. The simple question after many hours is: why not?

Comment: After some investigating I find that onAction handlers in the ListView aslo don't fire anymore, so there's obviously no 'connection' between the listview controller and the videoViewController. I think my besty option is to fx:include, but forget about a separate controller and paste the code into the first controller.

Comment: Don't do that. You will still have two controllers, they will just be from the same class. As well as still having the problem of how to communicate between the two controller instances, it will be extremely difficult to keep track of which fields are initialized in each instance. (One will have fields from one FXML initialized, one from the other FXML.) Just use the standard mechanism shown in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are loading the `playListView.fxml` file twice: once from the `<fx:include>` and once when you create the `FXMLLoader` in code and call `load()`. The node hierarchy (i.e the `AnchorPane` and all its content) created by the `<fx:include>` is displayed in your GUI; the one created by the `FXMLLoader.load()` call is not.

Since the controller you create is associated with the node hierarchy that is not displayed, methods you call on the controller will have no effect on your UI.

Instead of creating an `FXMLLoader` to get a controller instance, you can inject a controller from the included FXML directly into your `VideoViewController` using the [Nested Controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) technique described in the documentation.

To do this, first add a `fx:controller` attribute to your `playListView.fxml` root element:

playListView.fxml:

```
<!-- imports etc -->
<AnchorPane fx:controller="com.mycompany.packagename.PlayListViewController">
    <!-- etc etc -->
</AnchorPane>
```

Since you have an `fx:id="idPlayListAnchorPane"` attribute defined on your `<fx:include ...>`, you can inject the controller directly into the `VideoViewController` class by using an `@FXML`-annotated field called `idPlayListAnchorPaneController` (the rule is that you append "Controller" to the id):

```
public class VideoViewController {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane idPlayListAnchorPane;
    @FXML
    private PlayListViewController idPlayListAnchorPaneController ;

    // ...
}
```

and now you can just call methods on the controller as you need.

Comment: Yes! Thank you James. I had found an example in the book "Pro JavaFX8" and tried the FXML injection, but couldn't get it to work. The subtle difference between my feeble attempt and you working version was that I used private PlayListViewController playListViewController, where it should have been private PlayListViewController idPlayListAnchorPaneController. Things are a lot clearer now thanks to the JavafX Oracle ;-)